# How to sync midi to audio - Logic 8

Tags: midi, logic-pro, sync

I've annotated an audio file with the beat locations. Now I want to create a midi file that is synced with the audio.

The annotation is in xml format, but I can easily turn it into a csv or other format by writing a script to do so. I can also easily turn the beat timings into tempo data.

I'm hoping I can load a correctly formatted file into Logic and then I can use that as the tempo map.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

> but I can easily turn it into a csv or other format by writing a
>   script to do so.

If you are scripting in something like Perl or Python, there are MIDI libraries that are very easy to use. Instead of CSV, grab a library and output the MIDI that you want. Then drop the MIDI file into logic, and you will have your timing data.

Answer (score 0):

Annotated it in what ? how ? Logic will take any midi part and try and sync its tempo map to it, assuming its in some kind of straight 8s or 16s timing. Load the audio file into logic and convert audio to midi, then map the midi to tempo. strange way of doing it though, you can just map audio to midi easily inside logic anyway, no need for scripts n such, its easy to do tempo maps like that, I find melodyne infinitely better for sorting that stuff out tho.